# Returning an attribute from a fetch call using the Star Wars API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using the Star Wars API (SWAPI) for a project. I am in the process of learning fetch API. An issue I have is that, I have a section for species and when I press the button it returns certain attributes for that species. This is the code:

```
function getSpecies() {

let numberSpecies = Math.floor((Math.random()*37)+1)
let apiUrl = 'https://swapi.dev/api/species/' +  numberSpecies

fetch(apiUrl)
.then(function(response){
    return response.json()
})
.then (function(json){
    console.log(json)
    let name = document.getElementById('species-name')
    let classification = document.getElementById('classification')
    let designation = document.getElementById('designation')
    let language = document.getElementById('language')
    let lifespan = document.getElementById('lifespan')

    name.innerText = `Species Name: ${json['name']}`;
    classification.innerText = `Classification: ${json['classification']}`;
    designation.innerText = `Designation: ${json['designation']}`;
    language.innerText = `Language: ${json['language']}`;
    lifespan.innerText = `Lifespan: ${json['average_lifespan']}-years`;

   
    })

})   
}
```

So, when I press the button it fetches the info I want. However, there is a data attribute in the species section which is labelled 'people' and this show the people that belong to that species. The 'people' attribute is another link within the SWAPI. In other words, the attribute is made up of more urls which require using fetch.

Mu problem is I want to call those multiple urls and return the 'name' from them and then show it. So, if the species is 'Human' it has four people and therefore 4-url's and I want to fetch all those url's and only grab the 'name' of each 'Human'. This is what I have tried (it goes directly below the last line of code i.e below lifespan.innertext):

```
const peopleUrl = json.people
   
    peopleUrl.forEach(people = (data) => {
        fetch(data)
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json()
        })
        .then (function(json){
            console.log(json)
            let inhabitants = document.getElementById('inhabitants')

            inhabitants.innerText = json.name
        })

    })
```

This however, only return the name of the last person in the array and not all of them.
Is there a way I can fetch all the 'names'?

Comment: `Promise.all(json.people.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(details => details.name))).then(names => document.getElementById('inhabitants').innerText = names.join(', '));`

Comment: Note that you should always use variable names that actually reflect what they contain. json.people is an array of urls, not a single "peopleURL". And parsing JSON results in an object, not "json". And the element you're grabbing is exactly that, not "inhabitants". This will make your code much more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much. Would it be possible for you to just break down the code for me? I am very new to JS. And I did try similar solution to this like mapping to an array item but it didn't work.

Comment: Sure, here's a step-by-step live example: https://jsfiddle.net/ng1e9vr7/